# Plugins ignored a line breaks or <br> tag in the WordPress comment functions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I found out there is a plugins for ticket support. It uses the WordPress comments functions in the ticket system reply.

The issue is the plugin will not accept a line break or with <br.>. How can I make it to accept the <br.> tag or lines break?

```
                <div class="reply_form">
                    <?php
                    $comments_args = array(
                        'title_reply' => __('Reply', 'orbisius_support_tickets'),
                        'title_reply_to' => '',
                        'label_submit' => __('Send', 'orbisius_support_tickets'),
                        'comment_notes_after' => '',
                        'comment_notes_after' => '',
                        'comment_notes_before' => '',
                        'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . '</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="5" maxlength="65525" required="required"></textarea></p>',
                    );
```

Here is the plugin if you are interested. 
https://we.tl/t-iLFfJ3wKxH

Live Demo Website with the plugin installed: 
https://qwq.rf.gd/?orbisius_support_tickets_data%5Bticket_id%5D=51

Line-break applied.
[image: Pictures Examples]
After Submit, the line-break are not working.
[image: After Submit Comments]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `orbisius-support-tickets/modules/core/cpt.php` file the comment is sanitised as a single-line input with the function `sanitize_text_field()` which removes the line breaks. For a textarea field WordPress has `sanitize_textarea_field();`

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/

On that file, you can find the line

```
 $comment = sanitize_text_field( wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['comment'] ) );
```

And replace it with:

```
$comment = sanitize_textarea_field( wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['comment'] ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works after I added the CSS code! 

div.reply {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
  }

appreciate it!